# Fixing the separators in a link - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return a download link from my PHP API like below:

```
$response = ['link' => 'http://localhost/imageresizer/zip/'. basename($zipname)];
```

but the result is like this:

```
"link":"http:\/\/localhost\/imageresizer\/zip\/1638720308.zip
```

how can I fix these weird seperators?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... that isn't weird, that is how it is represented in JSON; that is how it escapes the `/` characters

Comment: On the frontend with JSON.parse(), it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by adding the option **JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES** the **json_encode**.
The implementation will look like this.

```
$response = ['link' => 'http://localhost/imageresizer/zip/'. "basename.zip"];
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```